# java 11 Error with Kerberos Authentication principal - KRB_CRED not generated correctly

Tags: java, oracle, kerberos, java-11

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The service in process is not supported. Operation unavailable (Mechanism level: KRB_CRED not generated correctly.)
```

I am getting this exception when my `HikariDataSource` is attempting to establish a connection with my `oracle` database by using `kerberos` as the means of authentication.

I am confident the issue is something to do with my principle not being accepted despite my credential cache file working perfectly fine for my other `java 8` projects.

The reason I believe its an issue with the principal is because I have a separate credential cache file that is generated on my server that uses a different principal than the one I would use locally. That credential cache file from my server works perfectly fine when it is used locally for this `java 11` project. However, I cannot locally generate credential cache files with that principal.

Additionally, I am using the same `krb5.conf` file so I don't understand how my principal is being accepted by 1 service but, not another... I also made sure to use the `java 11` version of the `kinit.exe` file when executing the below command although, I don't think that should matter.

```
$kinit -c credential_cache_file instance@domain.realm
```

Using other flags such as `-A` `-p` `-f` also gives me a separate error but, that type of credential cache file won't work for any of my `java 8` or `java 11` services.

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException: null
```

EDIT:
The lowest level error I am actually getting is this.

```
Caused by: sun.security.krb5.KrbException: Invalid option in ticket request. (101)
```

Comment: It seems like you should be using a keytab and not a cache file.  Why are you using a cache file? Why should this principle work?  Can you get more detailed about the principles and services that you are using so that we can discuss in better detail? You can use generic names but it would help to say "user1" rather than the "other credential file"

Comment: @MattAndruff How would you know whether to use a keytab or a credential cache file ? Is 1 a replacement for the other ? The local principal should work & does work for java 8 projects. It's based on my personal information. However, my java 11 projects only work for the principals that have already been assigned to a particular DB user.

Comment: Which encryption is specified in the `krb5.conf` file?

Comment: @Boris Theres 3 items in [libdefaults] for encryption & they all list `aes256-cts aes128-cts`

Comment: Your post still lacks a lot of details, you likely could get more help if you provide as much data as possible.  Could you add the complete error message? I'm not sure I understand why you can't create a cache locally.  What's the error message when you try?  Could you provide sudo server names and also provide sudo princple details?  If you want the issue resolve you need to provide details for people to help.

Comment: FYI, there are kerberos principals that are bound to servers and can't be used on other servers.  This could be your issue but it's not clear from the information you've provided.

Comment: Could you provide a narrative with commands/java versions and principles/servers?  This would help to sort the issue out.
(When i say sudo server/sudo principle I just mean "stand ins" or "aliases" for your servers so you don' t have to give us actual data points but representative data points.

Comment: When I moved from Java 8 to Java 11, I faced this bug: [LoginException: Message stream modified (41) for uppercase username with krb5](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8237647). I don't explicitly use any login and password. Since it was a call from Tomcat, the setup helped: 
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dsun.security.krb5.disableReferrals=true ${CATALINA_OPTS}"

Comment: Have you tried disable the forwardable ticket option in the Kerberos Config?

Comment: @DavidLukas Setting the disableReferrals didn't help sorry. Yes, I tried disabling forwardable ticket option but, still results in same issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually a bit more information and stacktrace would have helped in debugging the issue. As per the information provided above,

This `exception` happens when there is a mismatch in the `kerberos` `credential`. Then GSSException occurs and this message is generated.

```
Operation unavailable (Mechanism level: KRB_CRED not generated correctly.)
```

**Code Flow**

Step 1:
This message is part of `Krb5Context` class. Here `InquireType` is `KRB5_GET_KRB_CRED` which means it is  an attribute type for retrieving the `KRB_CRED` message that an initiator is about to send to an acceptor.
Links:  [Krb5Context](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.security.jgss/share/classes/sun/security/jgss/krb5/Krb5Context.java#L1464)   [InquireType](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/jdk.security.jgss/com/sun/security/jgss/InquireType.html)

```
try {
     byte[] krbCred = new KrbCred(tgt, serviceCreds, key).getMessage();
      return new KerberosCredMessage( sender, recipient, krbCred);
    } catch (KrbException | IOException e) {
       GSSException gsse = new GSSException(GSSException.UNAVAILABLE, -1,
                            "KRB_CRED not generated correctly.");
        gsse.initCause(e);
        throw gsse;
   }
```

Step 2:
Then it calls `KrbCred` class and here validation fails. This class encapsulates the KRB-CRED message that a client uses to send its delegated credentials to a server. In the condition check there is a mismatch in the Client of the Service Ticket with the client in Ticket Granting Ticket. So, as you mentioned it seems to me as a Principal issue.   Link : [KrbCred](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.security.jgss/share/classes/sun/security/krb5/KrbCred.java#L66)

```
PrincipalName client = tgt.getClient();
PrincipalName tgService = tgt.getServer();
if (!serviceTicket.getClient().equals(client))
    throw new KrbException(Krb5.KRB_ERR_GENERIC,
```

Step 3: First `KrbException` is thrown thereafter it is caught by the catch block and `GSSException` is thrown back with message as  `Operation unavailable`.   Link:  [GSSException](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.security.jgss/share/classes/org/ietf/jgss/GSSException.java#L195)

**Changes between Java 8 and Java 11**

There has been a lot changes for `kerberos` in `Java 11`. You can find it in the [changelog](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html). E.g.

- [Support cross-realm MSSFU](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html#JDK-8005819)
- [Support for canonicalize in krb5.conf](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html#JDK-8239385)
- [Support for Kerberos Cross-Realm Referrals (RFC 6806)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html#JDK-8215032)
- [LDAP Channel Binding Support for Java GSS/Kerberos](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11all-relnotes.html#JDK-8245527)

The are fewer `InquireType` in [Krb5Context](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/jgss/krb5/Krb5Context.java#L1421) of Java 8 compared to [Krb5Context](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.security.jgss/share/classes/sun/security/jgss/krb5/Krb5Context.java#L1464) of Java 11.

**Possible Solution**

The `Kerberos` client which you are using may not currently support the `'canonicalize'` setting in the configuration file `(krb5.conf)`. As a result, Name Canonicalization behavior cannot be customized. The client will claim support for it in every `TGT` request if `sun.security.krb5.disableReferrals` is `false`, and the KDC service may change the client name.

JDK 11: The '`canonicalize`' flag in the `krb5.conf` file is now supported by the JDK Kerberos implementation. When set to true.
The new default behavior is different from previous releases where name canonicalization was always requested by clients in `TGT` requests to `KDC` services (provided that support for [RFC 6806](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6806) was not explicitly disabled with the sun.security.krb5.disableReferrals system or security properties)

This issue was seen in few minor `Java` 8 version(1.8.0_242) as well. You can try the example in the ticket to reproduce. [JDK-8239385](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8239385) 
Some more information [JDK-8244465](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8244465)

Cross-Realm Referrals Support is enabled by default and 5 is the maximum number of referral hops allowed. To turn it off, set the `sun.security.krb5.disableReferrals` security or system property to false. To configure a custom maximum number of referral hops, set the `sun.security.krb5.maxReferrals` security or system property to any positive value.

You can try changing the `JAAS` config to use a ticket in the ticket cache created upfront using kinit.
You can try to upgrade the java version as well.

**Update from discussion in the comments section**:

```
by: sun.security.krb5.KrbException: Invalid option in ticket request. (101)
```

This could be linked to `proxiable=true` in your krb5.conf. Removing the value can help in resolving the issue.

```
Kerberos authentication fails with “java.nio.BufferOverflowException"
```

This issue could be related to the JDBC driver. The current version may  not support the operation. Upgrading or Downgrading `oracle jdbc driver` may lead to the resolution.

Comment: A very profound explanation on a very complex topic!

Comment: Thank you for the long & concise answer! Unfortunately, setting canonicalize or the disableReferrals properties didn't resolve in my case. My situation may just simply be that only the server principal is accepted for jdk11 versions ? I should have included that the lowest level error I had was this: `Caused by: sun.security.krb5.KrbException: Invalid option in ticket request. (101)`

Comment: If you have `proxiable=true` in your krb5.conf. Please `remove` that and check.

Comment: Invalid option setting in ticket request: There are some option  inside the [libdefaults] section of `krb5` file (say, forwardable=true, proxiable=true etc) which are used to provide KDCOptions when requesting a TGT using the AS-REQ message. For the TGT from the cache, these options are useless. Proving too many of them will only bring conflicts with your native TGT.

Comment: I have neither forwardable or proxiable in my `krb5.conf`. Although, using the '-f' flag to initialize my credential cache gives me [this](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2720963_1.html) type of error

Comment: Also, setting proxiable=true gives this different error: `Error: The service in process is not supported. No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Fail to create credential. (63) - No service creds)`

Comment: The link that you have shared, clearly tells that its a jdbc driver issue which is related to certain versions e.g. 18.3, 19.3, 20.2 etc. There has been new release of 21.X version. I am not sure if its fix is present or not. https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-21-1-c-downloads.html. You can try by either **upgrading** or **downgrading** the `oracle jdbc driver`.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error using Java 11/ojdbc10.jar which was confusing given the accepted answer being about needing to upgrade from Java 8 to 11. I tried all the proposed solutions there, but in the end what resolved the error and allowed my application to connect was using `kinit -f` instead of just `kinit`.

Credit to http://jiggermast.blogspot.com/2014/06/kerberos-invalid-option-setting-in.html

Relevant portions:

However, before trying to access the web application, the login module tries to go to the KDC (again ApacheDS) to get a ticket; however, before it gets there a KrbException is thrown (see below).

```
Found ticket for wmmnpr@EXAMPLE.COM to go to 
krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM 
expiring on Wed Jun 04 10:03:36 CEST 2014
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
KrbException: Invalid option setting in ticket request. (101)
 at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.<init>(KrbTgsReq.java:98) 
 at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.<init>(KrbTgsReq.java:62)
```

After looking at the sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq code at line 98 it occurred to me that it was the "forwardable" option that was causing problems. I then ran kinit as follows, with -f:

```
kinit.exe -f wmmnpr@EXAMPLE.COM
Password for wmmnpr@EXAMPLE.COM:
New ticket is stored in cache file C:\Users\wnpr\krb5cc_wnpr
```